# Transpose matrix with MPI_Alltoallv

Tags: c, mpi

I'd like to transpose a matrix b using MPI_Alltoallv and store it in bt.

Each process contain nlocal rows of b. For example:

Proc0:   0  | 10  | 20  | 30

Proc0:   1  | 11  | 21  | 31

Proc1:  100 | 110 | 120 | 130

Proc1:  101 | 111 | 121 | 131

I'd like bt being like:

Proc0:  0  | 1  | 100 | 101

Proc0:  10 | 11 | 110 | 111

Proc1:  20 | 21 | 120 | 121

Proc1:  30 | 31 | 130 | 131

The submatrices are stored in 2d arrays (b[0] contains the first row and b[1] the second row).
As suggested, I used MPI_Alltoallv(). Here is what I did:

```
    int n=4; //matrix of size 4x4
    int nlocal=n/nbProc; // the submatrices are of size 2x4

    int sc[nbProc];
    int dis[nbProc];
    int rdis[nbProc];
    for(int i=0;i<nbProc;i++){
        sc[i]=1;
    }
for(int i=0;i<nlocal;i++){//loop on the b[i]
    for(int j=0;j<nlocal;j++){ //loop on the bt[j]
        for(int k=0;k<nbProc;k++){
            dis[k] = j+k*nlocal;
            rdis[k] = i+k*nlocal;
        }
        MPI_Alltoallv(b[i],sc,dis,MPI_INT,bt[j],sc,rdis,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

However, I have 3 loops, I thought that I might have less. Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to call `MPI_Alltoallv` just once. All the submatrices have to be stored in one vector. But instead of storing for n first values, the first line, then the n next values, the second line etc... we store the m values which will go in the first process, the p next the ones which will go in the second process, etc... In the example I wrote, we would have `buf = {0,10,1,11,20,30,21,31}` for the first process. Then we use `MPI_Alltoallv` to send the values in a vector (called buft for example) and we then distribute the values in the matrix.

Note that there are two ways of storing the values in buf. The second one is `buf={0,1,10,11,20,21,30,31}` which is the one I used since I thought it was easier to implement, but the idea remains the same.

Also, this works even if the processes don't have submatrices of the same size (for example if our Proc1 would just have had 1 line in b).

Comment: Well my project ended, but I'm still curious on how to do it in the best way

Comment: is the solution you posted here faster than the solution from the code from the question itself ? thanks